# Unable to connect to web server 'IIS express'. when I added a new binding in applicationhost.config

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

What I want to accomplish is to be able to open the web application I'm running in Visual Studio from my Android phone, so I added new binding in the file applicationhost.config with my machine's IP:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51264:192.168.0.160" />
```

these are the tages inside `sites` tag:

```
<site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <site name="RazorPagesMovie" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="RazorPagesMovie AppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Mohamed El-Shawaf\Projects\Core\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51264:localhost" />
          <!--I'm adding the binding here-->
        </bindings>
      </site>
```

but when I run Visual Studio: this error message shows up:

> Unable to connect to web server 'IIS express'

[image]

To be honest, I'm new to these type of configurations and IIS, so I guess the bindingInformation is wrong

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Are you able to run it without specifying the binding, i.e. on http//localhost? Are you running visual studio as Administrator?

Comment: @Glubus yes , when I comment the binding line , visual studio runs without a problem. I run as admin , but still the same problem